# How do I fill height in list tag?

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to fill in the height of a `<li>` tag using only CSS?

The center column text is SOMETIMES longer than the sides so I need to increase their height when it's needed.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/U8WaH/16/

CSS:

```
.table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.table ul li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.table ul li.title {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.table ul li.delete, .table ul li.delete input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 20px;
}
.table ul li.result.delete {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.table input[type=submit] {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: 29px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.table ul li.title, .table ul li.result {
    display: inline-block;
}
.table ul li.last_replier {
    width: 140px;
}
.table ul li.subject {
    width: 315px;
}
.table ul li.status, .table ul li.category {
    width: 120px;
}
.table a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.list-emails-table {
    width: 900px;
}
.list-emails-table ul li.status {
    width: 80px;
}​
```

HTML:

```
<div class="table list-emails-table">
  <ul><li class="title delete">&nbsp;</li><li class="title category">Category</li><li class="title last_replier">Last Replier</li><li class="title subject">Subject</li><li class="title status">Status</li></ul>
  <ul><li class="result delete"><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" id="checkbox[]" value=""></li><a href=""><li class="result category">Info</li><li class="result last_replier">Somebodys Name</li><li class="result subject">Short Text</li><li class="result status">Status Here</li></a></ul>
  <ul><li class="result delete"><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" id="checkbox[]" value=""></li><a href=""><li class="result category">Info</li><li class="result last_replier">Somebodys Name</li><li class="result subject">Long Text - Long Text - Long Text - Long Text - Long Text - Long Text</li><li class="result status">Status Here</li></a></ul>
  <ul><li class="result delete"><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" id="checkbox[]" value=""></li><a href=""><li class="result category">Info</li><li class="result last_replier">Somebodys Name</li><li class="result subject">Short Text</li><li class="result status">Status Here</li></a></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not a solution, but a note: You wouldn't have this problem if you were using a table, and this is a situation where a table would be totally appropriate. (I mean you've even given your list the class `.table`!)

Comment: I would suggest you to use tables in this case for it semanticly fits much more than &lt;ul&gt;

Comment: I have to concur with @Nightfirecat. This is a scenario where a table would be the best solution.

Comment: @Nightfirecat I thought tables were bad to use these days. My HTML / CSS skills are lacking. Only been keeping up on my PHP for the last several years, and I only do Web Development as a hobby.

Comment: @Draven: That's correct, *but only in the context of using tables for layout*. Unless the rest of your website is set up using tables to create spacing (which, nobody would ever do that, right?), you should be fine, since table tags should be used to contain data that would be displayed in a table.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is: If you would use Excel (or Calc, for you LibreOffice people) to store this kind of data, you're good to go with using a table tag to display it on a website.

Comment: @Draven: If you dont want to use table, then its ok. But using ul and li in this case is never suggested. If you dont want to use tables then use divs. And if you use divs, your height problem will not be there. And  also the way you used anchor tags, I dont think thats correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hack-and-fix solution (just find-and-replacing your lists within lists with an honest-to-goodness table). The same effect could be achieved using `display: table`, `display: table-row`, and `display: table-cell`, but a `<table>` is more semantic in this case.

http://jsfiddle.net/U8WaH/17/

```css
.table {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.table tr td {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    list-style: none;
    border: 1px solid #C9C9C9;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.table tr td.title {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.table tr td.delete, .table tr td.delete input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 20px;
}
.table tr td.restrt.delete {
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
.table input[type=submit] {
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    height: 29px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -o-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
.table tr td.last_reptder {
    width: 140px;
}
.table tr td.subject {
    width: 315px;
}
.table tr td.status, .table tr td.category {
    width: 120px;
}
.table a {
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.tdst-emails-table {
    width: 900px;
}
.tdst-emails-table tr td.status {
    width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table tdst-emails-table">
  <tr><td class="title delete">&nbsp;</td><td class="title category">Category</td><td class="title last_reptder">Last Reptder</td><td class="title subject">Subject</td><td class="title status">Status</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="restrt delete"><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" id="checkbox[]" value=""></td><td class="restrt category">Info</td><td class="restrt last_reptder">Somebodys Name</td><td class="restrt subject">Short Text</td><td class="restrt status">Status Here</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="restrt delete"><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" id="checkbox[]" value=""></td><td class="restrt category">Info</td><td class="restrt last_reptder">Somebodys Name</td><td class="restrt subject">Long Text - Long Text - Long Text - Long Text - Long Text - Long Text</td><td class="restrt status">Status Here</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="restrt delete"><input type="checkbox" name="action[]" id="checkbox[]" value=""></td><td class="restrt category">Info</td><td class="restrt last_reptder">Somebodys Name</td><td class="restrt subject">Short Text</td><td class="restrt status">Status Here</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks Nightfirecat! Would you put an `<a>` tag inside each cell or use `onClick` on the cell?

Comment: To do what exactly? (If you mean to make the cells clickable to change the state of the checkboxes, you could attach an onClick handler to every cell, or fill each cell with a 100% height, 100% width `<label>` that is for the checkbox in its row)

Comment: Sorry, the links go to another page showing information about that user. I think I can just do an `onClick` on the `<tr>` tag though.